# Play 2.x framework Deploy on Heroku application error

Tags: java, heroku, deployment, playframework, web-deployment

I am deploying my play framework app on heroku , It is running fine locally with default in-memory database but when I am trying to deploying it on heroku with postgres, heroku compiles source files and launches the app with success but I can't open my application and get "Application Error". I tried this suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25821989/cant-find-favicon-ico-issue-in-play-scala) since log file indicated that has something to do with favicon but it didn't work. I am stuck and any help/suggestion/road ahead is highly appreciated.

my Proc file:

```
web: target/universal/stage/bin/assistu -Dhttp.port=${PORT}  -DapplyEvolutions.default=true -Ddb.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver -Ddb.default.url=${DATABASE_URL} ${JAVA_OPTS}
```

heroku logs says:

> 2015-02-13T10:54:16.519634+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx384m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=true
>
> 2015-02-13T10:54:16.886676+00:00 app[web.1]: Bad application path: -Xss512k
>
> 2015-02-13T10:54:17.581062+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
>
> 2015-02-13T10:54:17.596535+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
>
> 2015-02-13T10:54:18.819896+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=My-appname-5156.herokuapp.com request_id=f17c2b9f-7c05-4057-9efe-df99c4e792ea fwd="145.94.146.87" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
> 2015-02-13T10:54:20.051663+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=My-appname-5156.herokuapp.com request_id=41636ffd-49d7-41af-ae4f-6f36d615f0f3 fwd="145.94.146.87" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

Comment: can you post you full logs

Comment: @singhakash thanks for your reply is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is fixed , All I have is disabled evolution in application.conf file and applied script manually on PostgreSQL still have some issues though.

Comment: but if you will disable evolution than how can you create database

Comment: @singhakash So i detected the problem and I finally could not use the evolution at all !  In the end I applied the sql script directly into my app's postgresDB on heroku(by the way has some bugs. so i am still working on it).